# How do i read EXIF data from an image without the use of external scripts in python?

Tags: python, exif

How do i read EXIF data from an image without the use of external scripts in python? I don't want to use any prewritten scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [exif.py](http://exif-py.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/exif-py/source/EXIF.py?revision=19&view=markup).  If you don't want it to be an external **module** (it wouldn't necessarily be used as a **script** anyway), you can just copy all 1767 lines right inside your own module.  If your objection is to "prewritten", you can study and then rewrite the 1767 lines in question, if you have a few days to waste, but I don't understand why you'd want to do that.

Comment: Just to learn it. Hahaha, but if it is that many lines i will use the exif.py. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alex - the work has been done already!  But if you just want to flex your brain muscle, this is where I would start:

[EXIF Specifications](http://www.exif.org/specifications.html)

*edit*

Here is the official repository for the specification:

[Japan Electronics and Information Technology Industries Association - Digital Cameras](http://www.jeita.or.jp/cgi-bin/standard_e/list.cgi?cateid=1&subcateid=4)