# Read the Properties of a file using Python

Tags: python, windows, properties

Using Python in Windows, I want to list the Properties of an image file, specifically the properties and values contained in the Details tab. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: have you talking about image exif meta data??

Comment: serach "python win32 file properties"

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `details` tab is the EXIF metadata of the image.

TL;DR: Use [exif-py](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py)

Check this answer: [How do i read EXIF data from an image without the use of external scripts in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985218/how-do-i-read-exif-data-from-an-image-without-the-use-of-external-scripts-in-pyt#2985306)